Adding print statements to GCC driver code
I'm trying to display some print messages when gcc is executed. For example, when gcc source.c -o out.o is executed in the terminal, I want a print message saying "Building with GCC..." and if the build is successful, "Build Successful!" should be displayed otherwise "Build Failed!" should be displayed.
For the "Building with GCC..." message, I simply tried to add a print statement in the main method of the gcc driver code (named: gcc.cc) as shown below:
int driver::main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  bool early_exit;

  set_progname (argv[0]);
  expand_at_files (&argc, &argv);
  decode_argv (argc, const_cast <const char **> (argv));
  global_initializations ();
  build_multilib_strings ();
  set_up_specs ();
  putenv_COLLECT_AS_OPTIONS (assembler_options);
  putenv_COLLECT_GCC (argv[0]);
  maybe_putenv_COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER ();
  maybe_putenv_OFFLOAD_TARGETS ();
  handle_unrecognized_options ();

  printf (_("\nBuilding with GCC...:\n")); //ADDED

  if (completion)
    {
      m_option_proposer.suggest_completion (completion);
      return 0;
    }

  if (!maybe_print_and_exit ())
    return 0;

  early_exit = prepare_infiles ();
  if (early_exit)
    return get_exit_code ();

  do_spec_on_infiles ();
  maybe_run_linker (argv[0]);
  final_actions ();
  return get_exit_code ();
}

Doing this however resulted in errors while building the source code as shown below:
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
Makefile:24427: recipe for target 'configure-stage1-target-libgcc' failed
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/test/gccbuildnew'
Makefile:29699: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/test/gccbuildnew'
Makefile:1107: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

The following are portions of the Makefile concerned with the errors (I have added the Line numbers with #):
# --enable-pgo-build enables the PGO build.
# 1. First build with -fprofile-generate.
# 2. Use "make maybe-check-*" to generate profiling data.
# 3. Use "make clean" to remove the previous build.
# 4. Rebuild with -fprofile-use.
all:
    [ -f stage_final ] || echo stage3 > stage_final #Line:1107
    @r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    $(MAKE) $(RECURSE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) `cat stage_final`-bubble
    @: $(MAKE); $(unstage)
    +@r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    if [ -f stage_last ]; then \
      TFLAGS="$(STAGE$(shell test ! -f stage_last || sed s,^stage,, stage_last)_TFLAGS)"; \
      $(MAKE) $(TARGET_FLAGS_TO_PASS) all-host all-target; \
    else \
      $(MAKE) $(RECURSE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) \
        $(PGO_BUILD_GEN_FLAGS_TO_PASS) all-host all-target \
        ; \
    fi \
    && :

.PHONY: all-build

.
.
.
.PHONY: configure-stage1-target-libgcc maybe-configure-stage1-target-libgcc
maybe-configure-stage1-target-libgcc:
maybe-configure-stage1-target-libgcc: configure-stage1-target-libgcc
configure-stage1-target-libgcc:
    @[ $(current_stage) = stage1 ] || $(MAKE) stage1-start #Line:24427
    @$(SHELL) $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc
    @r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    TFLAGS="$(STAGE1_TFLAGS)"; \
    echo "Checking multilib configuration for libgcc..."; \
    $(CC_FOR_TARGET) --print-multi-lib > $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.tmp 2> /dev/null; \
    if test -r $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.out; then \
      if cmp -s $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.tmp $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.out; then \
        rm -f $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.tmp; \
      else \
        rm -f $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/Makefile; \
        mv $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.tmp $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.out; \
      fi; \
    else \
      mv $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.tmp $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/multilib.out; \
    fi; \
    test ! -f $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/Makefile || exit 0; \
    $(NORMAL_TARGET_EXPORTS) \
    CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)"; export CFLAGS; \
    CXXFLAGS="$(CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)"; export CXXFLAGS; \
    LIBCFLAGS="$(LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET)"; export LIBCFLAGS;  \
    echo Configuring stage 1 in $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc; \
    $(SHELL) $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc; \
    cd $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc || exit 1; \
    case $(srcdir) in \
      /* | [A-Za-z]:[\\/]*) topdir=$(srcdir) ;; \
      *) topdir=`echo $(TARGET_SUBDIR)/libgcc/ | \
        sed -e 's,\./,,g' -e 's,[^/]*/,../,g' `$(srcdir) ;; \
    esac; \
    module_srcdir=libgcc; \
    $(SHELL) $$s/$$module_srcdir/configure \
      --srcdir=$${topdir}/$$module_srcdir \
      $(TARGET_CONFIGARGS) --build=${build_alias} --host=${target_alias} \
      --target=${target_alias} \
       \
      $(STAGE1_CONFIGURE_FLAGS)

.
.
.
# Bubble a bug fix through all the stages up to stage 1.  They are
# remade, but not reconfigured.  The next stage (if any) will not be
# reconfigured either.
.PHONY: stage1-bubble
stage1-bubble:: 
    @r=`${PWD_COMMAND}`; export r; \ # Line:29699
    s=`cd $(srcdir); ${PWD_COMMAND}`; export s; \
    if test -f stage1-lean ; then \
      echo Skipping rebuild of stage1; \
    else \
      $(MAKE) stage1-start; \
      $(MAKE) $(RECURSE_FLAGS_TO_PASS) all-stage1; \
    fi

